# Why is the following not a primitive recursive function?

Tags: computational-complexity, recursion, computability

Consider the following set of four symbols $M=\{S,\square,\circ,-\}$.  Take $S\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ to be the successor function $x\mapsto x+1$.  Given $f,g\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, let $f\circ g$ denote the usual composition operator on two functions $x\mapsto f(g(x))$, let $f-g$ be the function where $$
x\mapsto \begin{cases}f(x)-g(x) & \text{if $f(x)\geq g(x)$}\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}
$$
and let $f^{\square}$ be the "iteration" of $f$ defined recursively by the conditions $f^{\square}(0)=0$ and
$$
f^{\square}(x+1)= f(f^{\square}(x)).
$$

Instead of writing expressions as above, I will instead use Polish notation.  So, for example $\circ \square SS$ is the Polish notation for $S^{\square}\circ S$, whereas $f- \square f$ is not a well-formed expression.  There is a very easy algorithm for determining whether any string of symbols from $M$ is a well-formed expression or not.

It is known, due to work of Daniel E. Severin, that every unary primitive recursive function is given by such a well-formed expression from the set $M$.

Now, consider the following pseudo-code (that I could easily implement on a computer):

Step 1: Take $n$ as input from the user.

Step 2: Create the ordered list of all strings of length $\leq n+1$ from the alphabet $M$, in the shortlex order (where we put $S<\square < \circ < -$).

Step 3: Run through this list and remove any string that does not yield a well-formed expression.

Step 4: Take the $n+1$st expression, $e$, from the remaining expressions in the list.

Step 5: Construct the code for the function $f$ represented by $e$.

Step 6: Print $f(n)+1$ to the screen, and terminate.

This program cannot describe a unary primitive recursive function, because it disagrees with them all (due to the "$+1$" part of Step 6).  I'm trying to figure out exactly where this fails primitive recursion.  I'm guessing it is in Step #5, where we replace the expression with the actual function it expresses.

However, I've been taught that primitive recursive functions are those computer programs that don't use unbounded searches/while loops, and I'm not seeing an unbounded search here.  I expect that an expert will immediately see the issue, and so I want to express thanks in advance for any comments and thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not step $5$, but step $6$. Or more precisely (as Andreas Blass comments below), it's the implicit "step $5.5$" which is needed to make sense of step $6$: computing $f(n)$ in the first place.

The issue is that **there is no "universal compiler"** for primitive recursive functions which is itself primitive recursive. The issue, intuitively, is that each individual p.r. function is "bounded complexity" in a particular sense but there is no single "bound on the bounds."

In fact there's nothing specific to primitive recursion here: by simple diagonalization, if $F=(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is any indexed family of **total** computable functions then there is no $F$-universal function in $F$ itself. (Totality plays a crucial role here of course.)

Comment: For the 6 steps in the question, this is the right answer.  But I'd be inclined to say that there's a missing step 5.5, namely "run the code produced in step 5 on input $n$." And then I'd say the "run" in this step is the problem. (I think the OP took step 6 to implicitly contain what I call 5.5, which puts the problem into step 6, but the implicitness can hide the problem.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, that's of course a more exact way of phrasing my answer. I'll edit to clarify that.

Comment: @AndreasBlass and Noah: Thanks! Supposing I have access to two functions $f$ and $g$, then I believe I can write a primitive recursive program that runs $f-g$ or $f\circ g$ or $f^{\square}$.  Similarly, I can write a program to handle a fixed finite number of concatenations of these operations.  Certainly, I can suppose $S$ is already compiled and ready to go. So, is the issue simply that I cannot run arbitrarily long concatenations of these processes, in a primitive recursive manner, because as I build up these functions, the run times are not *a priori* bounded in terms of the given data?

Comment: P.S. Regarding **partial** unary primitive recursive functions, is there a universal function for those?

Comment: @PaceNielsen  Re: your first comment, if I understand it correctly then yes, that's basically right. Re: your second comment, what is a partial unary primitive recursive function?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was thinking that might be troublesome. I suppose my real question is "Why did you emphasize the word **total**?"  Perhaps a better question would be to remove the word "primitive" and ask whether or not there is a universal function for the partial unary recursive/computable functions.  I would have guessed not (even if the usual proof for total functions doesn't work here).

Comment: @PaceNielsen Yes, there is a universal function for the partial computable unary functions - this is exactly what a universal Turing machine does.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks!